# video recorded with Mac's Photo Booth doesn't match session length. Can this be fixed?

Tags: video, video-editor, mac

A while ago I recorded a video with a friend which I didn't examine or watch until today. Upon opening it, I realized that the whole 15 minute video session had somehow only saved four seconds. We didn't click out of Photo Booth (like into the desktop or anything app), nor did we accidentally exit or force quit the app, all of which seem to be the most

I have already figured out a solution to how to fix this problem and my real problem is that I **really** want this video. This video is quite dear to me as my friend in it is taking a turn for the worst and I have since moved to a different state. There is no way that I can possible rerecord this video **:(**.

I don't know if the video is corrupted or not since it plays just fine, but is way too short. **Can this be fixed?** Possibly something in the encoding of the video to extend the length of the video? Is that even how it works? I know mov files are packages so maybe there is something restricting the length? The size is larger than I would expect a 4 second video to be which makes me hope what I just mentioned is possible.

Comment: Quick thing to check - look at frame size and frames per second. This will let you estimate an expected size for 15 minutes. If the file size is in that area, you could be in luck. Otherwise...

Comment: where do I check this at?

Comment: Check your resolution eg if 640x480 and 8 bit depth, that'll give you 300kb per frame, and at 25 fps you'll have 7Mb per second before compression. A comparison with other similar video you have recorded will give you an idea of what size you'd expect post-compression.

Comment: ah ok I got cha. Will give this a try later this evening

Comment: Were you ever able to get anywhere with this?